# analyse the result of accuracy in confusion matrix

Tags: python

I am new to ML and I am doing some exercises for understanding the algorithms and their results. I have a doubt to interpret the result of accuracy in this confusion matrix, I know my question is very simple.. but I need to know how exactly can I interpret this chart of the Confusion matrix.
ps: dataset heart failure - classification.
Thank you in advance for any explanation
[image]

Comment: There were 46 people with no heart failure in the dataset. Of these, 45 were classified correctly by the model. There were 14 people with heart failure in the dataset. Of these, 11 were classified correctly by the model.

Answer (score 0):

3 were predicted as 'no Heart-Fail', but the true class is 'Heart fail', so it is an **incorrect** classification

1 were predicted as 'Heart fail', but the true class is 'no Heart-Fail', so it is an **incorrect** classification

11 were predicted as 'Heart fail', and the true class is 'Heart fail', so it is an **correct** classification

45 were predicted as 'no Heart-Fail', and the true class is 'no Heart-Fail', so it is a **correct** classification

So, the total number of incorrect classification is: 3+1=4
and the total number of correct classification is: 11+45=56

Comment: Thank you a lot Mohaimin, now it's clear.

Comment: @Marzia if this was helpful, you can appreciate it by an upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Confusion matrices provide breakdowns for model classification performance on each category and are used to assess model quality.

Each row of the matrix denotes the true classes, while each column describes the predicted classes or vice versa as both variants in the literature.

The image below shows the configuration for reading the confusion matrix for what you have there (0 == no-heart fail, 1 == heart fail).

[image]

If the model correctly predicts the positive class, the outcome is a *true positive* (**TP**), and similarly, if the model rightly predicts the negative class, it is a *true negative* (**TN**).

A *false positive* (**FP**) is a mistakenly predicted positive class, and similarly, a *false negative* (**FN**) is an incorrectly predicted negative class.

As Arne pointed out there 46 people with no heart failure in the dataset (sum of the  no-heart failure row), and there are 14 people with heart failure in the dataset (sum of the heart failure row).

- 45 people who don't have heart failure were classified with no heart failure correctly (TN)
- 1 person with no heart-failure was mistakenly identified to have heart failure (FP)
- 11 people who had heart-failure were classified correctly to have heart failure (TP)
- 3 people who had heart failure were incorrectly classified not to have heart failure (FN)

Comment: Thank you Andy. appreciate your explanation..